# Construction of a theory using natural deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-languages, natural-deduction

Suppose I want to construct some first-order formal language $\mathcal{L}$ from signature $\sigma$ using natural deduction. That is, we have basic judgments like *"$\phi$ is a term"* or *"P is a formula"*  etc , and correspondent rules, e.g. :
$$\frac{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    f\in F   \quad  t_1 \, term \dots t_n \, term
  \end{array}}{f(t_1,\dots,t_n) \, term}$$

By this means we can construct appropriate formal language $\mathcal{L}$ with some set of terms and formulas of this language using these rules and judgements.

However, now I want to turn my language into a **theory**, i.e. define some certain set of sentences to be **axioms** (I suppose they are called *non-logical axioms*) from which by the means of some rules other sentences can be **derived**. And here comes my confusion, since natural deduction system is supposed to have *empty* set of axioms.

**Question**: How do we do this sort of definition of a theory in terms of natural deduction? Should we introduce some new judgements like *"A is an axiom"* and *"B is a theorem"* to our deductive system, or it can be done using some of the rules?

P.S. I know that there exists Hilbert-system of deduction that has non-empty set of axioms. However, as our language was initially constructed by natural deduction, I suppose that the definition of a theory over that language should also be in that same deductive system.

Comment: Empty set of *logical* axioms.

Comment: See e.g. Sara Negri & Jan von Plato, [Proof Analysis: A Contribution to Hilbert’s Last Problem](https://books.google.it/books?id=4peDUd3zBjIC&pg=PA50), Cambridge (2011), page 50 for examples.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, can we say that a theory over $\mathcal{L}$ is defined by natural deduction with empty set of *logical axioms*, some non-empty set of sentences called *non-logical axioms* and a set of rules? Or it would be better to define it with no axioms at al, just with rules?

Comment: Rules; the transitivity axiom: $(a < b \land b < c ) \to (a < c)$ can be rewritten as: $\dfrac {a < b \ \ \ \ b < c} {a < c}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tipically, they are written as rules.

You can see the natural deduction version of the [equality axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms):

> $$\dfrac {}{x=x} (= \text{I})$$
>
> $$\dfrac {s=t \ \ \ \ \ \ \phi[s/x]}{\phi[t/x]} (= \text{E})$$

In the same way, we can manage e.g. the *transitivity* axiom: $(a<b∧b<c)→(a<c)$ for $<$:

> $$\dfrac {a<b \ \ \ b<c}{a<c}(< \text{trans})$$